# Postgresql combining two tables SUM values with same columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have couple of table in my `Database` and all of them has a same `column` with name `User`. and now I want to calculate activity for each user on each table, so now I calculate activity on 2 table and you can see with name `Result 1` and `Result 2`.

Result 1:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Users  | Number of Insert|
+--------+-----------------+
| Liam   |        37       |
| Jacob  |        16       |
| Ethan  |        6        |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Result 2:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Users  | Number of Insert|
+--------+-----------------+
| Liam   |        7        |
| Jacob  |        10       |
| Ethan  |        9        |
| Elijah |        12       |
| Noah   |        5        |
+--------+-----------------+
```

so I want to combine this tow table but in user column I want remove delicate
and in `Number of Insert` column I want `SUM` same users and if there was no same users then show without sum
for example:
    Elijah , Noah there is no value in `Result 1` Table so finally question is here I want `output` to be like this but how?

OUTPUT :

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Users  | Number of Insert|
+--------+-----------------+
| Liam   |        44       |
| Jacob  |        26       |
| Ethan  |        15       |
| Elijah |        12       |
| Noah   |        5        |
+--------+-----------------+
```

> NOTICE : in the Result 1 and Result 2, Users column value most of the
>   time are same but not always.

Answer (score 3):

Full outer join and a coalesce?

```
 select
   coalesce (r1.users, r2.users) as users,
   coalesce (r1.number_of_insert, 0) + coalesce (r2.number_of_insert, 0)
 from
   result_1 r1
   full outer join join result_2 r2 on
     r1.users = r2.users
```

This presupposes your result 1 and 2 datasets are already formed as you have above.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select user, sum(num)
from ((select user, num
       from q1
      ) union all
      (select user, num
       from q2
      )
     ) q
group by user;
```